# VSCode -- update import paths on file name change?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I keep reading that VSCode does this natively, but I can't figure out how to get it working for me in a React project with jsx files. It doesn't work with any file type... jsx, js, tsx, ts, scss, etc.

I would LOVE VSCode to search my entire project for file imports and automatically update import paths everywhere when I move a file into another directory or otherwise rename it in the explorer.

It seems like something the editor would / should do out of the box without the need to edit the settings.json or use an extension.

Comment: Is this ***not*** working by default for you in VSCode? Seems I can't get VSCode ***not*** to try doing it when I move/rename files and directories.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. I must have an extension or setting that is overriding it.

Comment: I guess you try the typical debugging steps of disabling all the extensions and test that it works, then enable extensions 1-by-1 to find the offending extension that is breaking this experience.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah I reflexively do a `restart with extensions disabled` when I'm trying to solve VSCode issues. No luck. I've read somewhere that VSCode doesn't like JSX very much so it might be that. Maybe it's time to add TS and just TSX which ironically seems to be more supported.

Answer (score 2):

Unexpectedly, I found this worked after I updated the "Emmet: Include Languages" settings and added the item "javascript" with value "javascriptreact". (you can find this setting by searching for 'react' in the settings)

[screenshot of the Emmet Include Languages setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPv1Z.png)

Ofc, remember to Save-All after the refactor since VSCode doesn't do that. And, bear in mind this doesn't fix refactoring for css imports.

Hopefully this works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings for options like this that may have been set based on a dialog box selection

```
"javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
"typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never"
```

Just delete them and resave. No need to restart vscode.

You'll then get a dialog the next time you do it.